# SQL: How to insert data into SET datatype?

Tags: mysql, sql, set, sqldatatypes

How do I insert into table SET datatype?

**When i try to insert SET data (in MySQL) - it successfully inserts (no warnings or errors) but i get an empty cell instead of a cell filled by data.**

I tried like so:

```sql
INSERT INTO `individual_rate`(`user_id`, `movie_id`, `rate_code`, `rate_parts`) 
VALUES (3, 13,('1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0'),('81, 102, 0, 102'))
```

also tried like so:

```sql
INSERT INTO `individual_rate`(`user_id`, `movie_id`, `rate_code`, `rate_parts`) 
VALUES (3, 13,'1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0','81, 102, 0, 102')
```

It inserts data in to `user_id` and `movie_id`, but didn't do it for `rate_code` and `rate_parts`

table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `individual_rate` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate_code` set('n','a','f','d','s','e') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'rate code',
  `rate_parts` set('top_f','bottom_f','top_a','bottom_a') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'generated parts'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: What do you expect when you insert `'1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0'` to a column defined as `set('n','a','f','d','s','e')`?

Comment: @forpas I expect set to be populated with this data (numbers). This is not what i should expect?

Comment: But you defined the set to consist of: 'n','a','f','d','s','e' only.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I thought that `set` is an array and expected that I could fill in its fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `show warnings;` to see what happened.

Here is the results,

```
show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                         |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'rate_code' at row 1  |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'rate_parts' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

The insert statement can be

```
 INSERT INTO `individual_rate`(`user_id`, `movie_id`, `rate_code`, `rate_parts`)  VALUES (3, 13, 'n', 'top_f');



  select * from individual_rate;
  1     +---------+----------+-----------+------------+
  2     | user_id | movie_id | rate_code | rate_parts |
  3     +---------+----------+-----------+------------+
  4     |       3 |       13 |           |            |
  5     |       3 |       13 | n         | top_f      |
  6     +---------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can’t understand why such an warning is issued? I need to write an array to this field. For this, I used set, but it turns out that it can't be used? Do you know what then needs to be done to write an array to the field?

Comment: `set` means that its value can only be one of them, not the whole array.

Comment: Now I get it. I thought that `set` is an array and expected that I could fill in its fields.

Answer (score 0):

*Under the hood*, it uses numbers.  Actually bits in a bit string.  *You* use the *strings* you defined the `SET` with.

See also `ENUM`, which also maps strings into numbers.  In contrast, an `ENUM` column can be set to only one of the options.  A `SET` can be assigned any combination of the values.